# C# Copy file local to remote or remote to local

Tags: c#, ssis

I have custom component SSIS and I need copy the file from local to remote or from remote to local, but my remote address use credentials.

If I copy from remote credential location, it works, but opposite, it doesn't work.

Is there away option better?

Copy from remote to local:

```
using (new NetworkConnection(folder, new NetworkCredential(userName, password, domain)))
                    {
                        if (isCreateDirectoryDestination)
                        {
                            if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDestination)))
                            {
                                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDestination));
                            }
                        }

                        File.Copy(fileSource, fileDestination, isOverwrite);
                    }
```

Copy file from local to remote

```
if (isCreateDirectoryDestination)
                {
                    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDestination)))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileDestination));
                    }
                }

                File.Copy(fileSource, fileDestination, isOverwrite);
```

Comment: Perhaps you have read but not write privileges on the remote location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use impersonating

```
IntPtr tokenHandle = new IntPtr(0);  
tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;  

bool returnValue = LogonUser(<userName>, <domain>, <password>, 2, 0, ref tokenHandle);  
WindowsIdentity ImpersonatedIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenHandle);  
WindowsImpersonationContext MyImpersonation = ImpersonatedIdentity.Impersonate();
```